# failure to get list of selenium elements with chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Dim mylist As ChromeWebElement = driver.findElements(By.TagName("a"))
```

have been googling for hours, and just cannot get this to work, tried numerous changes the nearest I can get is the error message

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'
>   to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeWebElement'.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? You didn't say... it kinda looks like C# but not quite. The error is basically saying that `.findElements()` returns a collection of elements but you have defined myList as a single instance of an element. If you google tutorials on `.findElements()` for your language, you should find some simple examples of how to declare this properly.